# Trying to implement network error alerts into my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

Ok so I am trying to get this app to show network error alert codes. I have added the SystemConfiguration.framework framework and Apple's "Reachability" sample code.

Here is the viewcontroller.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Reachability;

@interface Test_Internet_ConnectionViewController : UIViewController {

    Reachability* internetReachable;
    Reachability* hostReachable;
}

@property BOOL internetActive;
@property BOOL hostActive;

- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice;

@end
```

Here is the viewcontroller.m file:

```
#import "Test_Internet_ConnectionViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h";

@implementation Test_Internet_ConnectionViewController

@synthesize internetActive;
@synthesize hostActive;

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        // check for internet connection
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

        internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
        [internetReachable startNotifier];

        // check if a pathway to a random host exists
        hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
        [hostReachable startNotifier];

        // now patiently wait for the notification
    }

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            self.internetActive = NO;

            UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Unavailable" message:@"This page cannot load, please check your internet connection and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorView show];
            [errorView release];

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;

        }
    }

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            self.hostActive = NO;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

        }
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    }

@end
```

If there is no internet upon opening the app the error works as intended, but if the app loses connection after the it has initially opened with an internet connection the error displays 3 times, when I obviously only want it to display once.

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error View delegate should probably be self and not nil, but I'm not sure if that will solve the problem. If it doesn't, the issue is probably that `NSNotificationCenter` is sending too many notifications to it's observer (in this case `checkNetworkStatus`. The simplest (but probably less elegant)  solution, is to keep a notice counter variable that is incremented when the error View is displayed, and only display the error View if the counter is zero. The better solution is to check the incoming notices, and respond to different notices differently (or not at all).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but changing the errorView delegate from self to nil did not solve the problem. Can you please explain to me how to do either of those two solutions? Thanks very much again.

Comment: I think it may be something in the Reachability class where it sends the notification 3 times, maybe in 3 different places. Do you know why it does this? Anyway I think the solution may be to remove the two calls I don't want from the Reachability class but I don't know how. Can you help with this?